# String Split Situation

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a fairly specific problem, where I want to take an equation and break it up, but also pay attention to negative numbers. Like:

```
exampleString = "12--5*-2"
```

Using that string I wish to split it into 3 number values:
`[12, -5, -2]`

Ive got it to work with double subtraction by splitting `"6-8--5"` by `"(?<!-)-"`
That will give me `[6, 8, -5]`

But I don't know how to modify it to work with all the operators, for example:
`"5*-2"` ---> `[5, -2]`

I feel like this should be able to work and I've spent a few hours searching but haven't come across anything that will do it. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like the following to split the string.

```
"(?<!\\G)[*/+-])"
```

The regular expression will split at any of the specified chars *,/,+,- iff the previous char was not a match (-> '--' will split only at the first '-').

Comment: Perfect works for everything as far as I can tell. Thanks.